# No error using wildcards when listed object does not exist

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

When executing this command: `get-process -name nosuchprocess`, I get and error `Cannot find a process with the name "nosuchprocess"`, and that's fine.

But after this one: `get-process -name nosuchprocess*`, there's no error, no output - just empty prompt.

The same behaviour can be observed with other commands (`get-item`, `get-childitem`, `select-string`).

What's the idea behind this? In both cases no objects are found, so why the output is different?

Comment: i´d guess because it cant name an item that doesn´t exist because it does not have a specific process / filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply the convention.

It's assumed that if you know the actual name of an object and you're trying to get the object that you're expecting it to already exist.  The expected number of results you're going to get is 1.  So you're either going to get 1 or get an error.  If you're not sure it's going to exist, you can use `Test-Path` or use `Get-ChildItem [...] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

If you're using wildcards, you're assumed to be getting either a collection of objects or a single object whose name you're not sure of.  You might even be looking for objects that don't exist, like `gci *.txt`.  It will therefore be often entirely logical to get 0, 1, or many objects.  If you need to test to see if you have results, you can use the `Count` property, like:

```
$x = Get-ChildItem *.txt;
if ($x.Count -gt 0) { [...] }
```

Although, beware that in old editions of PowerShell (v1, v2) you had to force the result to be an array even when 0 or 1 results are found by using `$x = @(Get-ChildItem *.txt);`.